# Is there any changes between .Net framework 3.5 to 4.8 means fundamentals were changed of Asp.Net in the year 2023 or not?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Just I want to make sure that there are any changes in the fundamentals of Asp.Net between the.Net framework 3.5 to 4.8 in the year 2023 fundamentals the same or changed of Asp.Net in the year 2023 And how many other changes could be there? Please help me

Comment: You already asked this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143340/is-there-any-changes-in-the-asp-net-with-net-framework-3-5-to-4-8-and-the-funda)). Nothing has changed from then.

Comment: @GuruStron: just make sure old .Net frameworks like 3.5 to 4.8 all fundamentals of asp.net will be the same even in 2023 or not?

Comment: There have been a lot of changes between Framework 4.8 and the current .Net7. So if you start learning, don't bother with the old stuff

Comment: @HansKeﬆing:Just I want to know fundamentals of asp.net were changed between framework 3.5 to 4.8 or not and even in the 2023 that all fundamentals of asp.net are same or not? that all fundamentals of asp.net are outdated with dot.net framework 3.5 to 4.8  now in 2023 please help me

Comment: There are several types of web-project, some (like webforms) are now (nearly) obsolete, others (like Blazor) new since .net5. What "fundamentals" do you mean exactly (please [edit] that into your question)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing:  all fundamentals of asp.net changed between frameworks 3.5 to 4.8 or not and do all fundamentals of asp.net still apply with the old framework like 3.5 to 4.8 in 2023 or not?

Answer (score 1):

Most fundamental changes were introduced in ASP.NET 4.0 in 2010, so Microsoft published an article to cover them,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Ever since then, while each .NET Framework 4.x release introduced many useful features, the impact on ASP.NET itself is quite limited.

Note that since ASP.NET Core was introduced in 2016, ASP.NET 4.x received almost no big feature update in the past few years. Recent changes were added mainly to enable smoother migration to ASP.NET Core.

Nobody has the luxury time to count "how many changes" are out there. And I am not answering that either.